# why does this filter not work?

Tags: c++, directshow

I am writing a filter using CBaseFilter as base class. 
I am trying to make it work to just forward the input media sample to the outputp in the graph.

I have created two pin classes, one for output and one for input.
I forward the data from the input pin via the method Receive to the output pin where i forward it using Deliver.
These methods are actually called because I have written log file entries every time these methd get called.

However when I use the filter in graphedt the result is that there is no data written into the file until I stop the graph. Then it always writes 64KB of something into the file.

The resulting avi file is of course not playable.

So what are these 64KB of data?
Do I have to define other methods than CBaseInputPin::Receive and CBaseOutputpin::deliver to make the dataflow work?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using CBaseFilter? For a Filter with input and output there is a directshow baseclass available: [CTransformFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or if you just have one input and one output pin the [CTransInPlaceFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is also a DirectShow sample how to implement CTransformFilter, the "[EZRGB24 Filter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

I think the 64Kb data is the Avi-Header, which is written after you stop the graph.

Comment: I use CBaseFilter because my final filter has at least 3 input pins

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to answer your question without knowing what how your graph looks and what kind of data you're trying to write. You can use GraphEditPlus to see the data flowing in your graph without writing to a file. Just insert some sample grabber instances and choose "watch grabbed samples" in the context menu (right click) for them.